# Dynamic Position Dropdown with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

all!
Here, I want to ask about jQuery...
How to make An element named `.eg-dropdown`...
Create this `.eg-dropdown` element to fit right `.btn-dropdown`...

Thanks, and Sorry for my less obvious English...

Index.html

```
<div class="btn-dropdown">Publik</div>

<ul class="eg-dropdown">
 <li>Teman</li>
 <li>Pribadi</li>
</ul>
```

Index.css

```
.btn-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: green;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Index.js

```
// DROPDOWN
$(document).ready(function(){
 var position_btn = $('.btn-dropdown').position();
 $('.btn-dropdown').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(position_btn);
 });

 $('.eg-dropdown').css({
  'position' : 'absolute',
  'top' : position_btn.top + $('.btn-dropdown').innerHeight(),
  'left' : position_btn.left
 });
});
```

SEE IN JSFIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/FIERMANDT/1kLvdys1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like below:

```js
// DROPDOWN
$(document).ready(function(){
    var position_btn = $('.btn-dropdown').position();
    var widthBtn = $('.btn-dropdown').width();
    var widthEg = $('.btn-dropdown').height();
    $('.btn-dropdown').on('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log(widthEg);
    });

    $('.eg-dropdown').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'top' : position_btn.top + $('.btn-dropdown').innerHeight(),
        'left' : position_btn.left + widthBtn - widthEg
    });
});
```

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var position_btn = $('.btn-dropdown').position();
  var widthBtn = $('.btn-dropdown').width();
  var widthEg = $('.btn-dropdown').height();
  $('.btn-dropdown').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(widthEg);
  });

  $('.eg-dropdown').css({
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'top' : position_btn.top + $('.btn-dropdown').innerHeight(),
    'left' : position_btn.left + widthBtn - widthEg
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: green;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-dropdown">Publik</div>

<ul class="eg-dropdown">
 <li>Teman</li>
 <li>Pribadi</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Firmansyah  what like this? you are providing links, not telling what you want in those links?

Comment: @Firmansyah  glad to help you.Please remeove  your other comments

Answer (score 0):

Instead of script you can use simple CSS for this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  $('.btn-dropdown > a').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).siblings('.eg-dropdown').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.eg-dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-dropdown"><a href="#" title="">Publik</a>
    <ul class="eg-dropdown">
     <li>Teman</li>
     <li>Pribadi</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-dropdown').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('.eg-dropdown').toggle('slow', function() {
      alert("fbhdh");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-dropdown">Publik
  <ul class="eg-dropdown">
    <li>Teman</li>
    <li>Pribadi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```